# Terminology problem: what if the historical term is not convenient for me while writing paper?

Tags: recurrence-relations, terminology, markov-chains, article-writing, spectral-radius

I am a graduate student and I am writing a paper.

For an irreducible Markov chain $P$ with spectral radius $\rho$, the historial literature says that it is **$\rho$-transient** iff its Green function at $1/\rho$ is finite.

My problem: in my paper, I am going to discuss several different Markov chains with distinguished spectral radii, it is inconvenient for me to decribe every Markov chains $P$ to be $\rho(P)$-transient (If I define the $\rho(P)$ to be its sepctral radius).

The most convenient way for me is that I expect a new name which is just the property to describe the Markov chains whose Green function at the reciprocal of its spectral radius is finite **without mentioning the value of spectral radius or the Markov chain itself.**

I want to give a new name to $\rho$-transience like 'spectral-transience', 'spectral-radius-transience' or 'rho-transience'.

How do you think these names or is there better names suggested? And generally saying is that acceptable to give a new name for personal convenience?

(I will mention the historical literatures which introduced and discussed this concept and the name over there when I am giving the definition.)

Comment: I would just define a transient Markov chain to be a Markov chain P whose Green function is finite at the reciprocal of the spectral radius of P. There doesn't really seem much purpose to define $\rho$-transience instead of just transience (do you ever say a Markov chain is $t$-transient for some $t \neq \rho$?)

Comment: @Motmot A transient Markov chain is already defined to have another meaning, which means the Green function at $1$ is finite. $t$-transience for $t\neq \rho$ occures in other literature but not mine, and it is another reason for me to avoid using it haha.

Comment: “Spectral transience” would be perfectly reasonable. Just be extremely careful to relate it to the standard terminology as prominently and clearly as possible, perhaps even remind the reader occasionally.